# avoid persisting memory state between requests in FastAPI

Tags: multi-tenant, fastapi, worker

Is there a way to deploy a `FastAPI` application so that memory state cannot be persisted between requests? The goal is to avoid leaking any data between requests in a multi-tenant application.

Starting up the application from scratch for every request seems not feasible since it takes too long. Is there a way in which the application is launched for every instance of the service but individual requests are handled by workers or threads that get purged after the request is handled so that any static property, singleton instance and such is destroyed and the next request is handled with clean memory?

Answer (score 0):

FastAPI is basically stateless by default. It actually takes extra work to persist data across requests through methods such connection pooling, reading a value from Redis, and so on. If you consider things such as starting up the server, loading a configuration, setting up path redirects, and so on to be "state", then FastAPI will not work for your purposes.

When you say "memory state", it sounds like you are trying to partition off instances of FastAPI server from each other so that they do not even use the same memory. This is not going to be a viable solution because most web servers, FastAPI included, are not designed for this type of segregating. By default, the requests from one tenant will not have anything to do with the requests from another tenant unless you write additional code that allows them to become related; so separating the concerns of the different tenants becomes a matter for the programmer, not the server's memory.

Instead, if you absolutely cannot let requests from multiple tenants inhabit the same memory, you'd be better off giving different tenants their own subdomain on the DNS level. Spin up a VPS and instance of your FastAPI program for each of them. That will truly prevent the requests from one tenant share any memory or state with the others.

Comment: The issue relating to the memory state is caused by uvicorn workers being used for more than one request before they are recreated. Upon subsequent requests a single worker may have some memory state such as static or global variables carried over from previous requests. This could be avoided by setting uvicorn to one worker per request. We currently cannot follow this as spinning up a worker takes too much time due to heavy imports but the solution will probably be to cut that down.